# Adding an extra condition to a group-by query makes it slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a query that selects a maximum value for a certain group, e.g.

```
select * 
from mytable 
where value in (select max(value) from mytable group by mygroupfield)
```

This is fast enough (~ 0.1 sec), but when I add an extra condition, e.g.

```
select * 
from mytable 
where value in (select max(value) from mytable group by mygroupfield)
AND mygroupfield='something'
```

the query becomes very slow (~ 4-5 seconds)

Both *value* and *mygroupfield* are indexed (non  unique, non clustered, if it matters). This table contains ~ 40,000 records.

I know I can do this:
`where value in (select max(value) where mygroupfield='something')` (which is also fast) but due to our architecture, that is not an option right now.

Is there a way to speed up this query?

Comment: What is the purpose of your second query ? What are you trying to achieve ? Performance aside, that logically second query does not sounds right

Comment: @Squirrel The first query is used to define a webservice in a 3rd party software we're using. This software lets users append certain conditions to the query, to further narrow down a set of records. In this particular case, a user sees all max values by default, but he may be interested in only one.

Comment: It helps if you can provide actual execution plans for the two queries and/or the results from running these with `SET STATISTICS IO ON;` It sounds like the second run has a poor query plan. Otherwise, some answers may fix the issue, but only by luck. Others (like index suggestions) will also likely help but may be one of several possible solutions.

Comment: @seanb The execution plan showed that the index on mygroupfield was ignored in favor of a clustered index scan, I suppose because mygroupfield wasn't selective enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a correlated subquery like the example below.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM mytable AS a
WHERE value IN (
    SELECT MAX(value) 
    FROM mytable AS b
    WHERE b.mygroupfield=a.mygroupfield 
    GROUP by mygroupfield
    )
    AND mygroupfield='something';
```

This index may help as well:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON dbo.mytable(mygroupfield) INCLUDE(value);
```

Comment: Thanks, both options give a massive increase in performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `row_number()` though not sure whether it'll serve your purpose or not

```
with cte as
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by mygroupfield order by value desc) as rn
from mytable 
where mygroupfield='something'
) 

select * from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: answer vul hyse dosto :)

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin, tui tik ta diye de :D

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
select t.* 
from mytable t
where t.value = (select max(t2.value)
                 from mytable t2
                 where t2.mygroupfield = t.mygroupfield
                ) and
      t.mygroupfield = 'something';
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `mytable(mygroupfield, value)`